# Arduino Due and BNO055

Tags: serial, sensors, arduino-due, communication, uart

For a physical activity monitoring project, I am developing a prototype based on an Arduino Due and several IMUs (BNO055 from Bosch).

I have to collect the data from the sensors simultaneously (3 for the moment). I want to use a Serial connection (Since the Arduino Due has 4 hardware serial ports).

- Here comes the first issue : I use the [shuttleboard BNO0055](http://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/products/shuttleboards/BNO055_Shuttleboard_Flyer.pdf), and because of my limited knowledge, I'm not sure I did the right wiring. As I understood in the [datasheets](http://www.bosch-sensortec.com/en/homepage/products_3/sensor_hubs/iot_solutions/bno055_1/bno055_4), the PS0 pin must be connected to the GND and PS1 to the incoming voltage. The COM0 to the RX of the Arduino and COM1 to TX. I am confused by the documentation, I can't figure out which pin of the shuttleboard are the COM0 and COM1. (I can't post the pictures of my wiring since it's my first post here).
- And now there is a second problem: If the wiring is good, how can I communicate with the sensor to get the Euler angles? The BNO055 sensor does the fusion data itself, and gives the quaternions or the Euler angle. Bosch provides a [library](http://https:%20//github.com/BoschSensortec/BNO055_driver). I have never used a library, and I don't know the syntax to ask the sensor to give the Euler angles. Can someone give me a code to do this? Or at least explanations on the syntax I should use?

Comment: `PS0 pin must be connected to the GND and PS1 to the incoming voltage. The COM0 to the RX of the Arduino and COM1 to TX.` according to figure 10 that would be correct. The library you linked to only works for I2C, so that won't work. Is there any reason to use UART over I2C?

Comment: At the end of the project I should have 5 IMU connected. With the Arduino due I know I can have 4 IMUs, but I would miss one. For now I can use I2C, I tried, and It's the same problem, I don't know if my wiring is good, I tried several wiring and each time I used the I2C Scanner and it failed everytime

Comment: Update : The I2C Scanner found the device at address 0x29, only when I link I2C_MODE_ADR_SEL to the incoming voltage